# TFS Build call cmd never finished

Tags: tfs, compilation, visual-studio-cordova

My TFS Build system just call a PowerShell script that do the compilation (through msbuild), package the application, deploy the database, etc...

Unfortunatly, I don't understand why the script won't finish. I try exit 0, call exit 0, but it always end by a timeout :

```
> Build succeeded.
>     0 Warning(s)
>     0 Error(s) Time Elapsed 00:00:13.48 
>     "MOVING APK IN SHARED FOLDER"
>     1 file(s) copied. 
>     "SUCCESS !" 
>      C:\Build\SmartLingo>exit 0
```

Then the build keeps running........ forever until one hour (or until I stop it myself).

I finally noticed that the line which is responsible of this non-sense is the following :

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=Android;MDAVSIXDIR="%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools";NODEJSDIR="%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\nodejs";NPMINSTALLDIR="%APPDATA%\npm";LANGNAME="en-us";BUILDVERBOSITY=Normal C:\Build\Test\Test.jsproj
```

So it seems that this compilation execute a thread or something like that and  is never finished...

Any idea how to make it works ?
Thanks

Comment: [Start-Job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756924/managing-the-running-time-of-background-jobs-timing-out-if-not-completed-after) along with setting a timeout.

Comment: Start-Job will launch the script and if the timeout is reached, will fail. this is not what I want. My job take around 1 min, I just want that at the end of my bash script, TFS understand that the script is finished and can be successful.

Comment: So your blackbox script is not working. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I add some details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TFS 2015, I strongly recommend you look into switching to the new build system which does not rely on MSBuild. There's a [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/cordova/cordova-build) and even a [Visual Studio Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-vsclient.cordova-extension) that you can use now.

However, if you are using TFS 2013 and must rely on MSBuild, there is a problem you can run into for Android specifically that is caused by a daemon process that is started by recent versions of Cordova that can cause the problem you describe.

The [tutorial](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfs2013/) has been updated and there are some improvements with TACO Update 5, but here's the summary on this specific problem:

Create stopGradle.cmd in the hooks\after_compile folder in your project with the following contents:

`IF EXIST platforms\android platforms\android\gradlew --stop`

You'll also need to specify the DebuggerFlavor to get it to build an apk.  Check out the [tutorial](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfs2013/) for details.